# Why does Erlang not have a C NIF drop-in replacement for calloc?

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

Why does Erlang have a C NIF drop-in replacement for `malloc`, `enif_alloc`, but not `calloc`?  Thereby forcing one to use `memset()` after `enif_alloc` for array access.

Comment: I don't know Erlang very well, but in C `calloc()` isn't all that useful. Well-written C code that avoids reading array elements that it hasn't written can use `malloc()` rather than `calloc()`. And `calloc()` isn't guaranteed to set pointers to null or floating-point objects to 0.0 (though it happens to do so on most systems).

Comment: Keith, you should post that as an answer. Answers as comments are not a very good idea since it defeats the purpose of the Q&A system.

Comment: So your saying since well written c code will have set array elements itself, that there is no need for calloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I assume this has to do with the fact (from documentation):

**"NIFs where introduced in R13B03 as an experimental feature."**

On a side note, the Erlang review board is also quite conservative, probably due to the history of being born from a telelcom company, and that is understandable for fault tolerant languages.

I guess I don't see the problem you have since you are always welcome to write a proper port using calloc() and use the old marshaling methods.
http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/erl_interface.html

Happy C coding!

Comment: Congrats on registering.  I was under the impression NIF's would be fastest. On my system I get a 7 us overhead for calling one.  I wonder what that will be with a port, I assume if it's a system port it will be close to the same speed.  But at least I still get that raw c power - born of pure c.